# .on('mouseover') did not feedback info

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I have such a snippet of ajax request:

```
    <div>
        <h4>Comments</h4>
        <!-- <form action="/article/comment/create/{{ article.id }}" method='post'> -->
        <form action="#">
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" name='comment' id="commentContent"></textarea>
        <br>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="commentBtn">Post Your Comment</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div><!--/class="col-xs-8 col-md-8">-->
</div><!-- row -->

<script src="/static/js/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/jquery-csrf.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var article_id = article.id;
    var num_pages = {{ page.num_pages }};

    $("#commentBtn").on('mouseover', function(e){
        e.preventDefualt();
        alert("clicked")
        var comment = $("#commentContent").val();
        var param = {
            "article_id": article.id
            "content": comment};

        $post("/comment/create/", param, function(data){ 
            var ret = JSON.parse(data);
            if (ret["status"] = "ok") {
                $("#commentConent").val("");
                window.location.href = "/article/detail/{{ article.id }}?page_number=" + num_pages;
            } else {
                alert(ret["msg"]);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

I set the event type as `mouseover`,
However, when I place my mouse over the button "#commentBtn",
nothing occurs.

What's the problem it might be with my codes?

Comment: Should be `$.post` not `$post`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have many syntax errors and typos  in your code , and that's the cause of your problem , you write every thing correct , but I suggest you should use IDE like [vscode](https://code.visualstudio.com/) to help you find this errors , IDEs help in finding undefined variables , or any syntax errors , to help you avoid this kind of problems and bugs , if you look at your code you'll see that ,

- `var num_pages = {{ page.num_pages }};` this code should be like this 
      `var num_pages =  page.num_pages ;` if you try to extract **num_pages** into variable , also you can use [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) which is ES6 feature
- also you should change `$post` to `$.post` and `e.preventDefualt();` to `e.preventDefault();`
- I suggest that you should learn about ES6 features which will make your code better and enhance your development with JavaScript , things like `const` `let` and arrow functions and many  great features , you can take an overview of this features here

> [es6-features](http://es6-features.org)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    // var article_id = article.id;
    // var num_pages = {{ page.num_pages }};

    $('#commentBtn').on('mouseover', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('clicked');
        var comment = $('#commentContent').val();
        var param = {
            // "article_id": article.id
            content: comment,
        };

        $.post('/comment/create/', param, function(data) {
            var ret = JSON.parse(data);
            if ((ret['status'] = 'ok')) {
                $('#commentConent').val('');
                window.location.href =
                    '/article/detail/{{ article.id }}?page_number=' + num_pages;
            } else {
                alert(ret['msg']);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
        <h4>Comments</h4>
        <!-- <form action="/article/comment/create/{{ article.id }}" method='post'> -->
        <form action="#">
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" name='comment' id="commentContent"></textarea>
        <br>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="commentBtn">Post Your Comment</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div><!--/class="col-xs-8 col-md-8">-->
</div><!-- row -->
```

Answer (score 3):

Typo, use:

```
e.preventDefault();
```

Also:

```
$.post
```

And, at the end:

```
$("#commentContent")
```